# Count query using 2 attributes of object using Spring mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework

I am using mongo to store the following data.

```
Class Restaurant {
  String status;
  String name;
  String location;
}
```

The amount of data in my mongo is very large. I want to get the count on basis of status and name of the Restaurant for a given list.

There are 2 input lists:

```
List<String> restaurants = {'PizzaHub', 'Cheese&u', 'FoodForU', 'Mcdonalds'}
List<String> status = {'Open', 'Closed', 'Open', 'Open'}

public interface RestaurantRepository extends MongoRepository<Restaurant, String> {
     public long countByNameAndStatus(String name, String status);
}
```

What I am currently doing is looping through the two arrays and finding the count.

```
for(int i = 0; i < restaurants.size(); i++) {
    restaurantRepo.countByNameAndStatus(restaurants.get(i), status.get(i))
}
```

But this is relatively slow and I want to write an aggregate query for the same.

There are 1307 Restaurants of type 'PizzaHub' which are 'Open', 154 'Cheese&u' which are 'Closed', 964 'FoodForU' which are 'Open' and 1034 'Mcdonalds' that are open.

The response type of my function is Map. So response is

```
{
   PizzaHub: 1307,
   Cheese&u: 154,
   FoodForU: 964,
   Mcdonalds: 1034
}
```

Comment: Please provide some examples like what happens with your current code? what count did you get? But what is your expected count and why it should be that?

Comment: @palaѕн 
The expected count should be all restaurants of type  'PizzaHub' which are 'Open', 'Cheese&u' which are 'Closed' , 'FoodForU' which are 'Open' and 'Mcdonalds' which are 'Open'
The count I am getting is correct but the query time is large. I want to reduce the time by using aggregate query with the given list rather than firing it for every element in the list separately.

Comment: Ok, Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempts for the aggregate query and say specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: You can try the repository method along with the `@Query` annotation: [Query Methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries.json-based)

Comment: @prasad_ `@Query` works exactly same as countByNameAndStatus. Mongo repository automatically understands by function name and `@Query`  is not necessary

Comment: You have to use the list collections as input to the queries.